# Smooth Scroll with onFling?

Tags: android, android-layout

I decompiled an App which shows PDFs but my issue is that I would like to implement a continuous vertical scroll (just like Google PDF Reader)...

Any help would be greatly Appreciated...

Here's the Code for its PageView -

```
public class PageView extends View implements OnGestureListener, OnScaleGestureListener {
   protected DocumentActivity actionListener;
   protected Bitmap bitmap;
   protected int bitmapH;
   protected int bitmapW;
   protected int canvasH;
   protected int canvasW;
   protected GestureDetector detector;
   protected boolean error;
   protected Paint errorPaint;
   protected Path errorPath;
   protected Paint linkPaint;
   protected Link[] links;
   protected float maxScale;
   protected float minScale;
   protected ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;
   protected int scrollX;
   protected int scrollY;
   protected Scroller scroller;
   protected boolean showLinks;
   protected float viewScale;

   public PageView(Context var1, AttributeSet var2) {
      super(var1, var2);
      this.scroller = new Scroller(var1);
      this.detector = new GestureDetector(var1, this);
      this.scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(var1, this);
      this.viewScale = 1.0F;
      this.minScale = 1.0F;
      this.maxScale = 2.0F;
      this.linkPaint = new Paint();
      this.linkPaint.setARGB(32, 0, 0, 255);
      this.errorPaint = new Paint();
      this.errorPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 80, 80);
      this.errorPaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0F);
      this.errorPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      this.errorPath = new Path();
      this.errorPath.moveTo(-100.0F, -100.0F);
      this.errorPath.lineTo(100.0F, 100.0F);
      this.errorPath.moveTo(100.0F, -100.0F);
      this.errorPath.lineTo(-100.0F, 100.0F);
   }

   public void goBackward() {
      this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
      if(this.scrollY <= 0) {
         if(this.scrollX <= 0) {
            this.actionListener.goBackward();
            return;
         }

         this.scroller.startScroll(this.scrollX, this.scrollY, 9 * -this.canvasW / 10, this.bitmapH - this.canvasH - this.scrollY, 500);
      } else {
         this.scroller.startScroll(this.scrollX, this.scrollY, 0, 9 * -this.canvasH / 10, 250);
      }

      this.invalidate();
   }

   public void goForward() {
      this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
      if(this.scrollY + this.canvasH >= this.bitmapH) {
         if(this.scrollX + this.canvasW >= this.bitmapW) {
            this.actionListener.goForward();
            return;
         }

         this.scroller.startScroll(this.scrollX, this.scrollY, 9 * this.canvasW / 10, -this.scrollY, 500);
      } else {
         this.scroller.startScroll(this.scrollX, this.scrollY, 0, 9 * this.canvasH / 10, 250);
      }

      this.invalidate();
   }

   public boolean onDown(MotionEvent var1) {
      this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
      return true;
   }

   public void onDraw(Canvas var1) {
      if(this.bitmap == null) {
         if(this.error) {
            var1.translate((float)(this.canvasW / 2), (float)(this.canvasH / 2));
            var1.drawPath(this.errorPath, this.errorPaint);
         }
      } else {
         if(this.scroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
            this.scrollX = this.scroller.getCurrX();
            this.scrollY = this.scroller.getCurrY();
            this.invalidate();
         }

         int var2;
         if(this.bitmapW <= this.canvasW) {
            this.scrollX = 0;
            var2 = (this.canvasW - this.bitmapW) / 2;
         } else {
            if(this.scrollX < 0) {
               this.scrollX = 0;
            }

            if(this.scrollX > this.bitmapW - this.canvasW) {
               this.scrollX = this.bitmapW - this.canvasW;
            }

            var2 = -this.scrollX;
         }

         int var3;
         if(this.bitmapH <= this.canvasH) {
            this.scrollY = 0;
            var3 = (this.canvasH - this.bitmapH) / 2;
         } else {
            if(this.scrollY < 0) {
               this.scrollY = 0;
            }

            if(this.scrollY > this.bitmapH - this.canvasH) {
               this.scrollY = this.bitmapH - this.canvasH;
            }

            var3 = -this.scrollY;
         }

         var1.translate((float)var2, (float)var3);
         var1.scale(this.viewScale, this.viewScale);
         var1.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, (Paint)null);
         if(this.showLinks && this.links != null) {
            Link[] var4 = this.links;
            int var5 = var4.length;

            for(int var6 = 0; var6 < var5; ++var6) {
               Rect var7 = var4[var6].bounds;
               var1.drawRect(var7.x0, var7.y0, var7.x1, var7.y1, this.linkPaint);
            }
         }
      }

   }

   public boolean onFling(MotionEvent var1, MotionEvent var2, float var3, float var4) {
      if(this.bitmap != null) {
         int var5;
         if(this.bitmapW > this.canvasW) {
            var5 = this.bitmapW - this.canvasW;
         } else {
            var5 = 0;
         }

         int var6;
         if(this.bitmapH > this.canvasH) {
            var6 = this.bitmapH - this.canvasH;
         } else {
            var6 = 0;
         }

         this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
         this.scroller.fling(this.scrollX, this.scrollY, (int)(-var3), (int)(-var4), 0, var5, 0, var6);
         this.invalidate();
      }

      return true;
   }

   public void onLongPress(MotionEvent var1) {
      boolean var2;
      if(!this.showLinks) {
         var2 = true;
      } else {
         var2 = false;
      }

      this.showLinks = var2;
      this.invalidate();
   }

   public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector var1) {
      if(this.bitmap != null) {
         float var2 = var1.getFocusX();
         float var3 = var1.getFocusY();
         float var4 = var1.getScaleFactor();
         float var5 = (var2 + (float)this.scrollX) / this.viewScale;
         float var6 = (var3 + (float)this.scrollY) / this.viewScale;
         this.viewScale = var4 * this.viewScale;
         if(this.viewScale < this.minScale) {
            this.viewScale = this.minScale;
         }

         if(this.viewScale > this.maxScale) {
            this.viewScale = this.maxScale;
         }

         this.bitmapW = (int)((float)this.bitmap.getWidth() * this.viewScale);
         this.bitmapH = (int)((float)this.bitmap.getHeight() * this.viewScale);
         this.scrollX = (int)(var5 * this.viewScale - var2);
         this.scrollY = (int)(var6 * this.viewScale - var3);
         this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
         this.invalidate();
      }

      return true;
   }

   public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector var1) {
      return true;
   }

   public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector var1) {
   }

   public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent var1, MotionEvent var2, float var3, float var4) {
      if(this.bitmap != null) {
         this.scrollX += (int)var3;
         this.scrollY += (int)var4;
         this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
         this.invalidate();
      }

      return true;
   }

   public void onShowPress(MotionEvent var1) {
   }

   public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent var1) {
      float var2 = var1.getX();
      float var3 = var1.getY();
      boolean var4 = this.showLinks;
      boolean var5 = false;
      if(var4) {
         Link[] var8 = this.links;
         var5 = false;
         if(var8 != null) {
            float var9;
            if(this.bitmapW <= this.canvasW) {
               var9 = (float)((this.bitmapW - this.canvasW) / 2);
            } else {
               var9 = (float)this.scrollX;
            }

            float var10;
            if(this.bitmapH <= this.canvasH) {
               var10 = (float)((this.bitmapH - this.canvasH) / 2);
            } else {
               var10 = (float)this.scrollY;
            }

            float var11 = (var2 + var9) / this.viewScale;
            float var12 = (var3 + var10) / this.viewScale;
            Link[] var13 = this.links;
            int var14 = var13.length;
            int var15 = 0;

            while(true) {
               var5 = false;
               if(var15 >= var14) {
                  break;
               }

               Link var16 = var13[var15];
               Rect var17 = var16.bounds;
               if(var11 >= var17.x0 && var11 <= var17.x1 && var12 >= var17.y0 && var12 <= var17.y1) {
                  if(var16.page >= 0) {
                     this.actionListener.gotoPage(var16.page);
                  } else if(var16.uri != null) {
                     this.actionListener.gotoURI(var16.uri);
                  }

                  var5 = true;
                  break;
               }

               ++var15;
            }
         }
      }

      if(!var5) {
         float var6 = (float)(this.canvasW / 3);
         float var7 = var6 * 2.0F;
         if(var2 <= var6) {
            this.goBackward();
         }

         if(var2 >= var7) {
            this.goForward();
         }

         if(var2 > var6 && var2 < var7) {
            this.actionListener.toggleUI();
         }
      }

      this.invalidate();
      return true;
   }

   public void onSizeChanged(int var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {
      this.canvasW = var1;
      this.canvasH = var2;
      this.actionListener.onPageViewSizeChanged(var1, var2);
   }

   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent var1) {
      this.detector.onTouchEvent(var1);
      this.scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(var1);
      return true;
   }

   public void setActionListener(DocumentActivity var1) {
      this.actionListener = var1;
   }

   public void setBitmap(Bitmap var1, boolean var2, Link[] var3) {
      if(this.bitmap != null) {
         this.bitmap.recycle();
      }

      this.error = false;
      this.links = var3;
      this.bitmap = var1;
      this.bitmapW = (int)((float)this.bitmap.getWidth() * this.viewScale);
      this.bitmapH = (int)((float)this.bitmap.getHeight() * this.viewScale);
      this.scroller.forceFinished(true);
      int var4;
      if(var2) {
         var4 = this.bitmapW - this.canvasW;
      } else {
         var4 = 0;
      }

      this.scrollX = var4;
      int var5 = 0;
      if(var2) {
         var5 = this.bitmapH - this.canvasH;
      }

      this.scrollY = var5;
      this.invalidate();
   }

   public void setError() {
      if(this.bitmap != null) {
         this.bitmap.recycle();
      }

      this.error = true;
      this.links = null;
      this.bitmap = null;
      this.invalidate();
   }
}
```

Comment: So in line with other questions on SO, what have you done/tried to solve the issue? As I understand it, the code you've shown here is the code from the decompiled app or am I mistaken? If this is the case, why would you expect to get any help when all you've shown is how to reverseengineer someone elses work and steal their code? Sorry for being so blunt.

Comment: @Darwind well I'am not stealing, but rather just Tryin to implement a smooth vertical scroll for myself.. :P Can u help?

Comment: Ok, if you're not merely stealing the code, what have you tried so far? Don't show the whole code, but show us what you've tried.
Maybe I can help, but I'm not reading through de-compiled code that might not be part of the issue.

Comment: @Darwind I have tried changing the onFling and onScroll... But messed up badly, so I posted here for help.. Plzz Help :)